# How can I group a list of values by cities in a given time interval

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am developing a web application where I would like to calculate the quantity of production per city for the last five years. Now I am able to calculate the quantity by city, but I am not to limit it to a given period interval.
Here is the views

```
def ProductionStat(request):
  productions = Production.objects.all()
  lignes = LigneProduction.objects.all()  
  # Quantity of production par islands
  quantityByIle = []
  list_iles = []
  Quantities_by_ile=LigneProduction.objects.values('ile_id').annotate(Total_quantite=Sum('quantite_produit'))
  for dict_item in Quantities_by_ile:
    quantityByIle.append(dict_item['Total_quantite'])
    if dict_item['ile_id']==1:
      list_iles.append('Ngazidja')
    elif dict_item['ile_id']==2:
      list_iles.append('Mohéli')
    elif dict_item['ile_id']==3:
      list_iles.append('Anjouan')
    else:
      list_iles.append('Mayotte')

  print(list_iles)
  print(quantityByIle)
  context={
          'list_iles':list_iles,
           'quantityByIle':quantityByIle,
          }
  return render(request, 'siga/StatProduction.html', context)
```

Here is the models

```
class LigneProduction(models.Model):
    ile = models.ForeignKey(Iles, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    production = models.ForeignKey(Production, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    produit = models.ForeignKey(Produits, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    annee_production = models.CharField(_('Année de production'), max_length=20)
    superficie_cultive = models.IntegerField(_('Superficie cultivée'), null=True, default=0)
    quantite_produit = models.IntegerField(_('Quantité de production'), blank=True, default=0)
    prix_production = models.DecimalField(_('Coût de production'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    utilisation = models.BooleanField(_('Fértilisée (Oui/Non)?'), default=False)
    intrant = models.ForeignKey(IntrantAgricole,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    kilogramme = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
```

Please assist.

Comment: Try filtering using the range condition. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: Yes, this solution is working. Thanks, Guillaume